# Export data from SQL database to script file in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, export

I want to export the data in my SQL database to a script file (file filled with insert commands) using C# but I can't get it done. Is there a setting for it in the `BACKUP DATABASE` statement?

Comment: This seems to be a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801175/export-a-sql-server-database-from-c-sharp-and-re-import

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Sql Server doesn't do `INSERT`-based exports. That's more of a MySql thing, and Sql Server people tend to look down on MySql for making you do it that way... it's much slower, creates larger files, and is error-prone with regards to certain characters or keywords getting into the scripts.

Comment: Hi Joel, thanks, that explains why I couldn't find it... MS SQL Server Management Studio does provide this option, so I thought it was kind of standard. Maybe I find some c# that can do it. Bas